# Spring Boot Application Won't Start After Upgrading Spring Cloud Consul

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

My Spring Boot application will not start after upgrading Spring Cloud Consul from version 1.0.2.RELEASE to version 1.3.0.RELEASE. It is failing with the following

```
error:java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.cloud.consul.serviceregistry.ConsulServiceRegistryAutoConfiguration.consulServiceRegistry
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:64) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:102) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:178) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:140) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:333) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:678) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:520) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at <redacted>.Main.main(Main.java:103) [query-service.jar!/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:54) [query-service.jar!/:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_172]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @ConditionalOnMissingBean annotations must specify at least one bean (type, name or annotation)
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:68) ~[spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.validate(OnBeanCondition.java:279) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.<init>(OnBeanCondition.java:275) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:111) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    ... 22 more
```

I am not able to share the entirety of my code/configuration because it's proprietary to my employer, but I will try to share the relevant details...please let me know if there are more I can provide

```
Spring Boot version: 1.3.5.RELEASE
Spring Cloud Sleuth version: 1.0.4.RELEASE
Spring Dependency Management plugin: yes
```

Comment: Are you using the release train BOM?

Comment: Hi, @spencergibb - thanks for the reply! Unfortunately, I don't understand your question and as such do not know how to answer it.

Comment: Show your pom.xml or build.gradle

Comment: Hi, @spencergibb -  I do not think I am able to share my build.gradle in its entirety as it is proprietary to my employer. Are there specific questions I can answer for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make the following changes to get things working:

```
Spring Cloud Consul: 1.0.4 to 1.3.0
Spring Cloud Sleuth: 1.0.2 to 1.3.0
Spring Boot: 1.3.5 to 1.5.0
JSON Path: 0.8.1 to 2.2.0
JSON Smart: 1.1.1 to 2.3
Bouncy Castle: 1.47 to 1.59
Log4J: 2.5 to 2.7
```